Unable to save MSG file with HTML data using Outlook.MailItem
I have following code to save HTML data in MSG file but its never saving as HTML and when I open it, its shiwing in PLAIN text

            // Specify the HTML body content with colored text
            string htmlBody = "<html><head><title></title></head><body><h1 style='color: blue;'>Test Email</h1><p style='color: green;'>This is a test email with colored text.</p></body></html>";

            // Create a new Outlook application instance
            Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

            // Create a new MailItem object
            Outlook.MailItem msg = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            // Set the HTML body content
            msg.HTMLBody = htmlBody;

            // Set the body format to HTML
            msg.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

            // Specify the path to save the .msg file
            string pathToSaveMsg = @"D:\email_body2.msg";

            // Save the message as a .msg file
            msg.SaveAs(pathToSaveMsg, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);

its showing in PLAIN text instead of HTML

when i open this MSG online, its showing me in HTML format but when i open it in outlook, its showing in PLAIN text...
also when i add below code its fetching it as a PLAINTEXT
Outlook.MailItem _mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(@"D:\email_body2.msg");
var htmlTemp = @"D:\email_body2.html";
var _htmlBody = _mailItem.HTMLBody;

Does it work if you call msg.Save() before calling SaveAs?

thanks for response.  I have removed this code and changed the requirements.
